# Using Promises in script tag not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

My below code is used to append scripts in DOM using promises. (All below code executes inside iframe for A-frame technology and my code is being generated using Google Blockly[Block-based coding] )

```js
export const appendScript = async({
      src,
      aframeWindow,
      code,
      id
    },
    doc,
    callback,
  ) =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    const startDate = new Date();
    const script = doc.createElement('script');
    if (src) script.src = src;
    if (code) {
      script.text = code;
    }
    if (id) {
      script.id = id;
    }

    doc.head.appendChild(script);
    if (callback) callback();
    if (code) {
      if (callback) {
        callback();
      }
      console.log(aframeWindow.onGreenPlayButtonClicked, "===="); // undefined when code string contains await outside ongreenplaybuttonclicked fn
      resolve('resolved');
    } else {
      script.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const endDate = new Date();
        const seconds = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000;
        console.log('script loaded: ', src, `took ${seconds} to load`);
        resolve('resolve2');
      });
    }
  });
```

The below script is my function that calls appendscript.

```js
const callAppendScript = async code => {
  const CODE_VERSION = aframeWindow.CODE_VERSION;
  code = `
           async function main(inPlayMode) {
              let CURRENT_CODE_VERSION = CODE_VERSION;
              ${code};
            }
            main();
          `;


  let x = await appendScript({
      code,
      aframeWindow,
      id: 'code'
    },
    aframeWindow.document,
  );
}

callAppendScript(code);
```

My code string 1 that generates  :  (donot work)

```js
async function main(inPlayMode) {
  let CURRENT_CODE_VERSION = !inPlayMode ? 0 : window.CODE_VERSION;
  var greeting;
  greeting = await HatchTranslateEngine.translate(`Hello`, 'en'); //async

  window.onGreenPlayButtonClicked = async function onGreenPlayButtonClicked() {
    await MinecraftAvatar.speakSound(greeting, true)

  };
}
main();
```

My code string 2 that generates : (works)

```js
async function main(inPlayMode) {
  let CURRENT_CODE_VERSION = !inPlayMode ? 0 : window.CODE_VERSION;
  var greeting;
  greeting = Hatch.convert(`Hello`, 'jp'); //syncrhonous

  window.onGreenPlayButtonClicked = async function onGreenPlayButtonClicked() {
    await MinecraftAvatar.speakSound(greeting, true)

  };
}
main();
```

My code string 3 that generates: (still works)

```js
async function main(inPlayMode) {
  let CURRENT_CODE_VERSION = !inPlayMode ? 0 : window.CODE_VERSION;
  var greeting;


  window.onGreenPlayButtonClicked = async function onGreenPlayButtonClicked() {
  greeting = await HatchTranslateEngine.translate(`Hello`, 'en'); //async this still works (inside playbtn)
    await MinecraftAvatar.speakSound(greeting, true)

  };
}
main();
```

Whenever i click play button, `callAppendScript(code)` gets executed , and when it does so,

For ***code string 1***, it gives me **undefined** in  `aframeWindow.onGreenPlayButtonClicked` (incorrect)
For ***code string 2***, it gives me **function signature of onGreenPlayButtonClicked** in  `aframeWindow.onGreenPlayButtonClicked` (correct)

So, why is it not working for case 1 , I tried everything but could not figure it out. I only found out that for any `await` keyword that is outside onGreenPlayButtonClicked, I get `aframeWindow.onGreenPlayButtonClicked` which is  inside `appendScript` function.

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in the `appendScript` waits for the promise that the `main()` call returns. If you are asynchronously initialising `onGreenPlayButtonClicked`, it won't be immediately available after appending the script element.

I would suggest you try

```
const callAppendScript = async code => {
  const CODE_VERSION = aframeWindow.CODE_VERSION;
  code = `
    async function main(inPlayMode) {
      let CURRENT_CODE_VERSION = CODE_VERSION;
      ${code};
    }
    // no main() call here
  `;
  await appendScript({
    code,
    aframeWindow,
    id: 'code'
  }, aframeWindow.document);

  console.log(aframeWindow.onGreenPlayButtonClicked, "before");
  await main();
//^^^^^^^^^^^^
  console.log(aframeWindow.onGreenPlayButtonClicked, "after");
}
```

Comment: ThankYou , it works, I will have to brush up my skills

Comment: What if i am not using async in ongreenplaybuttonclicked ? Will it hoist the function declaration of ongreeenplaybuttonclicked ? I thought it would get hoisted and i could call it, but still it was undefined, any particular reason ?

Comment: @Coderboi The problem is not with the `async` code in `onGreenPlayButtonClicked`, it's with the `async` code in `main` itself - specifically, the ``await HatchTranslateEngine.translate(`Hello`, 'en')``.